# AFNetworking Response Error only for specific URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

Im trying to get response from using GeoNames API. and here my Code

```
  NSMutableDictionary * parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:params];

    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesJSON"];

    AFHTTPSessionManager * manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager POST:@"" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {

        [delegate didReceiveNearByLocationResponse:responseObject];

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);

    }];
```

Im getting following error.

`Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: forbidden (403)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff013d840f0 {Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ff013d07440> { URL: http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesJSON/ }`

i tried with `hurl.it` to check whether response coming or not. and its coming fine.

Surprise is im using same above code for various other requests with only changing URL and those are working fine.

**UPDATED**

And previously it worked for the following code. and i did some code quality adjustment and transferred the code to above. then got the problem

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

        NSDictionary *params = @{@"lat": lat,
                                 @"lng": lon,
                                 @"username" : @"testing"
                                 };
        [manager POST:@"http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesJSON" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. i even upgraded the AFNetworking to 3.0 from 2.X

and Code Changed like below. Special Changes `GET`

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager GET:@"http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesJSON" parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success!");
    [delegate didReceiveNearByLocationResponse:responseObject];
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

When I just enter the URL http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesJSON into a browser, I get the following JSON:

```
{"status":{"message":"Please add a username to each call in order for geonames to be able to identify the calling application and count the credits usage.","value":10}}
```

So I suspect that, at the very least, you need to change your 'POST' to a 'GET':

```
[manager GET:@"" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
    [delegate didReceiveNearByLocationResponse:responseObject];
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}];
```

Beyond that, based on the returned content, it looks like you'll need some additional application-level logic to provide user identification/authentication in order to get the actual data you're interested in, but the above change should at least trigger an invocation of the success block.

Comment: it didnt work. :( btw i updated the question more. because it worked fine before

Answer (score 0):

"Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"
because the AFNetworking only support @"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript"
you should add a @"text/html" type

```
[manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];




NSMutableDictionary * parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:params];

    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesJSON"];

    AFHTTPSessionManager * manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    //insert this code
    [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager POST:@"" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {

        [delegate didReceiveNearByLocationResponse:responseObject];

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);

    }];
```